# PHP My code doesn't send to the right page after using edit button

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have the following problem. I created a .php file that creates(extends) two new pages. In the ***first page*** there is a button called ***submit*** which after click on it send me to the next page called ***editname***. When I made click on the button (**edit**)of the second page, it send me to the third page called ***recorndname***. In the third page, there are two buttons called ***update*** and ***delete*** which send me to the second page. But, actually it is working as it should. Here is part of my code.

```
//here is my main class
class main {

 public function __construct() {

  $page_request = 'homepage';

  if(isset($_REQUEST['page'])) {

    $page_request = $_REQUEST['page'];

  }

  $page = new $page_request;

  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {

    $page->get();

  } elseif ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    $page->post();

  } else{
    $page->delete();
  }

 }

}
```

Here is my page class. In this part seems neither one of the functions are called.

```
//Page class
class page {

 public function get() {
   echo 'I am a get method page';
 }

 public function post() {

   echo 'I am a post method';
   $user=new users();
   //$user->addUser($_POST["firstname"],$_POST["lastname"],$_POST["email"]);
   if($_POST['botton'] == 'Submit'){
      $user->addUser($_POST["firstname"],$_POST["lastname"],$_POST["email"]);
   } else if($_POST['botton'] == 'Update'){
      $user->update($_POST["email"],$_POST["firstname"],$_POST["lastname"]);
   } else if($_POST['botton'] == 'Delete'){
      $user->deleteUser($_POST["email"]);
   }
 }

  public function delete(){
   echo 'I am a delete method';
  }
 }
```

Here are my extended pages.

```
 //Page classes
    class homepage extends page {

 public function get() {
 echo 'homepage';
 echo'<form action="projectBackup.php?page=editname" method="post">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="">
    <br>
    Email Address:<br>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit">
    </form>';
 }

}

class editname extends page {
   public function post(){
     echo 'editname';
     $users=new users();
     $userlist=$users->listUsers();
     echo '<table><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Email Address</th></tr>';
     foreach($userlist as $Kuser=>$user){
       echo '<tr><td>'.$user['fname'].'</td><td>'.$user['lname'].'</td><td>'.$Kuser.'</td><td>';
       echo '<form action="projectBackup.php?page=recordname" method="get">
             <input type="hidden" name="email" value="$Kuser">
             <input type="submit" value="Edit"></form>';
     }
     echo '</table>';
   }
 }
    class recordname extends page {
public function get() {
echo 'recordname';
$users=new users();
$userlist=$users->listUsers();
echo'<form action="projectBackup.php?page=editname" method="post">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="$userlist[$_GET["email"]["fname"]">
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text name="lastname" value="$userlist[$_GET["email"]["lname"]">
    <br>
    Email Address:<br>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="$_GET["email"]">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Update">
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Delete">
    </form>';
 }

}
```

Can someone help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `But, actually it is working as it should` not a good description of your problem

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's great you've included all this code - that's really helpful. But I agree, could you please expand upon what is going on? Perhaps use a step-by-step example of what you click on and when it breaks (including the error you get) eg: 1. fill in form for first page 2. click submit 3. fill in form for 'editname' page 4. click update 5. it explodes with the error X

Comment: Also: I notice you have a bunch of 'echo' statements for each page. It'd help us if you show us what gets echoed to the page during correct and incorrect page flow, and what you expect it to be when it's fixed.

Comment: Well, what is happening is that when i am in homepage and i make click on submit button, it sends me to editname page which is correct. But in editname page when i make click on edit button it doesn't not send me to recordname page but homepage. That is problem.

Comment: You guys will know what I am talking about if you add echo $page_request; in the main class before the if statement.